# VBA multiple use of GoTo ErrorLabel and GoTo CodeStart

Tags: vba, goto, type-mismatch

I've got a code here to check whether a number is a prime number or not. Generally, it works perfectly fine. The only problem I got is that if you enter something that is not a number more than 1 time in a row, I get the Type Mismatch Error. I don't want that which is why I went with a GoTo pattern in the first place. Any ideas why this doesn't work as intended?

```
Private Sub Primerus_Click()

CodeStart:
On Error GoTo ErrorLabel
Dim Nummer As Long, i As Long, prime As Boolean
prime = False
Nummer = InputBox("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl ein", "Mathe für Idioten", "Bitte hier die Zahl eingeben")
For i = 2 To Nummer - 1 Step 1
    If Nummer Mod i = 0 Then
    prime = True
    End If
Next i
    If prime = False Then
    MsgBox ("Dies ist eine Primzahl.")
    Else: MsgBox ("Dies ist keine Primzahl.")
    End If
    Exit Sub

ErrorLabel:
MsgBox ("Dies ist keine Zahl!")
GoTo CodeStart

End Sub
```

Comment: Lookat err.clear and Resume Next. You need one or the other.

Comment: @Noodles Hey do you want to elaborate on that? I've tried both and no joy here.

Comment: The error is not reset in your code. From Help. Use the Clear method if you need to explicitly clear the Err object after handling an error. This is necessary when using inline error handling with On Error Resume Next. Visual Basic calls the Clear method automatically whenever it executes any type of Resume statement, Exit Sub, Exit Function, Exit Property, or any On Error statement.

Comment: Are you sure? If I understood this right, the On Error statement in my code should make VB call the Clear method anyway every loop. (Because it is in the loop.)